# SvelteKit: config.kit.target is no longer required, and should be removed

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Compile time error - config.kit.target is no longer required, and should be removed

When you runs the svelteKit app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the 'target' option under kit in your project's root 'svelte.config.js' and it resolve the error.